# Ignore, or avoid circular reference in UDF?

Tags: vba, user-defined-functions, circular-reference

I am trying to make a planner. I have a table which I want to be something like this:

| ID | Parent ID | Start Date | Duration | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 01/01/2021 | 10 | 11/01/2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 06/05/2021 | 2 | 08/05/2021 |
| 3 | 2 | 08/05/2021 | 1 | 09/05/2021 |
| 4 | 3 | 09/05/2021 | 5 | 14/05/2021 |
| 5 | 2,3,4 | 14/05/2021 | 4 | 18/05/2021 |

The Start date will be based on matching the Parent ID to the Task ID, so task 2 follows task 1, task 2 follows task 3 etc. I also want to be able to test against multiple tasks that might be happening at the same time, so task 5 can start after tasks 2, 3 or 4, which ever ends last.

I wrote this UDF for the start date calculation.

```
Option Explicit

Function LastPredecessor(PreList As String, TaskList As Range, TaskDueDate As Range)

Dim ID
Dim Dates
Dim nPres, i As Integer

On Error Resume Next

Pres = Split(PreList, ",")
nPres = UBound(Pres)
ReDim Dates(0 To nPres, 0)

For i = 0 To nPres
    Dates(i, 0) = IDX_Match(CInt(Pres(i)), TaskList, TaskDueDate)
Next

LastPredecessor = WorksheetFunction.Max(Dates)

End Function

Function IDX_Match(LookupVal, MatchRange As Range, LookupRange As Range, Optional MatchType As Integer = 0)
    
    IDX_Match = WorksheetFunction.Index(LookupRange.Value2, WorksheetFunction.Match(LookupVal, MatchRange.Value2, MatchType))
    
End Function
```

The function is called in the start date in the table like this

=LastPredecessor([@Parent ID],[ID],[End Date])

It works well if the end date is independent of the start date, but as soon as I try to update the end date, and add start date + duration as the calculation for end date, it generates a circular error.

I am sure I am doing something very simple wrong, but would be great to know what I need to do to fix this.

EDIT:

Thanks to @Toddleson, the following is a slightly modified version

```
Function LastPredecessor(PreList As String, EndDates As Range, IDColumn As Range) As Date
    Dim Preds() As String, PredDates() As Long
    
    Preds = Split(PreList, ",")
    ReDim PredDates(UBound(Preds))
    For i = LBound(Preds) To UBound(Preds)
        PredDates(i) = IDColumn(WorksheetFunction.Match(CInt(Preds(i)), IDColumn, 0)).Offset(0, EndDates.Column - IDColumn.Column).Value2
    Next i
    LastPredecessor = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(PredDates)
End Function
```

Comment: Can you clarify on the purpose of the function and what a successful result looks like?

Comment: Hi @Toddleson

What's shown in the table is the imagined successful output. The aim is to generate a Gannt table and chart where one task can not start until another or multiple tasks are finished, so in the example above, Task 5s start date should be whatever the greatest end date is between tasks 2, 3 and 4. I can do this using normal excel functions for a single parent task, but I need the UDF for cases where there are these competing predecessor tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I rewrote the function. It should be doing exactly what you described to me.

```vb
Function LastPredecessorV2(PreList As String, EndDates As Range, IDColumn As Range) As Date
    Dim Preds() As String, PredDates() As Long
    
    Preds = Split(Replace(PreList, " ", ""), ",")
    ReDim PredDates(UBound(Preds))
    For i = LBound(Preds) To UBound(Preds)
        PredDates(i) = IDColumn.Find( _
                        What:=CInt(Preds(i)), _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole _
                    ).Offset(0, EndDates.Column - IDColumn.Column).Value2 'Corrected
    Next i
    LastPredecessorV2 = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(PredDates))
End Function
```

Here's how the input of the arguments looks. Those ranges can be the entire column and it  still works.
[image: Example of arguments]

All of the End Dates are using the formula (Start Date + Duration in Days). The first task start date is the only independent value in the column, all the other ones are using the formula.

Edit:
I should mention that you can insert columns in-between the ranges and the function will still work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I modified slightly as I think it gives more flexibility( the proposed I think would only work in col A), but this def got me to a working solution. Thanks

Comment: Good point, the `.Column - 1` stops working if you move the table. The `-1` should be `- IDColumn.Column` as you have put in your modified version.